# Variable is not being passed to the back end using RESTful

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am just trying to pass "hello" to the back end of my code through the url. Instead of a "hello" string being sent to my back end java code i get an empty sting.

Here is my backend code:

```
@GET
@Path("getJob/{stepName}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Step> getStepByName(@PathParam("stepName") String stepName) {
    String x = stepName;
    System.out.println(x);
    return null;

            //List<ModuleProcCount> pusher = statements.inMod(dbc,theReader);
            //for(ModuleProcCount p : pusher) {
            //  input.add(p.modName + " " + p.modCount);
            //}
            //  return result;


        }
```

and here is my javascript:

```
performanceApp.controller("homectrl", function($scope, $http){
    var x = "rest/performance/getJob/hellp";
    $http.get(x).then(function(response){

    }); 


});
```

Not sure what im doing wrong or what is wrong with this code, seems pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, don't really get all you are saying, but i am making some assumptions here, as in which you are using AngularJS, and just for starters, that is your first mistake, but well... on the question.

What you are getting wrong is problably the header of your request, you will have to set a different type of header in you client side javascript code so your server knows and understand the type of media it is receiveng.

[AngularJs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) have a nice example around it:

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

I would suggest you inspect the request made, it can be done at *network tab* of you browser devtool, make sure your content-type is *application/json*

Comment: Hmm I dont think so because the code runs just the string that is sent to my java back end is empty instead of heaving "hello"

Comment: Yes, you should hit the endpoint, but the server will not understand the payload of the request as it is expecting a different kind of media, usually by default we send a *text/plain* content-type and you are specifieng a json media type in your server

Comment: Yeah I just tried to remove the json and replace as plain text and no dice